# Dealing with USB Unplugging?

Tags: serial, arduino-due

The following code, debugs SerialUSB Native Port, *plugged* to a PC, and *connected* through a Terminal Monitor (such as *Termite*, with any bps, 8N1, RTS/CTS).

At start, the ports seeks for communication, and you see fast blinks.

If **`SerialUSB`**, **Plugged** and **Connected**, communication happens, a.k.a. slow blinks.

But if USB is **Unplugged** after **`SerialUSB`**, even if you **Disconnect** it before, the code turn into an **`Halt`** state, a.k.a. no blinks.

If you **Plug** back the USB, it returns to **`!SerialUSB`**, so if you **Disconnect** (if it were connected) and **Connect** back the terminal, it recovers the **`SerialUSB`** state, not without a `reset()` line to react.
Seems the same happens for `Serial`.

**Any clue about why the Arduino goes into that `Halt` state after a USB disconnect?**

**How should we deal with that? How one should prevent this state?**

Most people asserts this is a power source problem. This happens *with* and *without* the 5V Barrel Power Source.

```
// ARDUINO DUE BLINK LED
void setup(){
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialUSB.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial){
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);delay(500);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("System Reset");
}    
void loop(){  
  int n=0;
  while(!SerialUSB){
    Serial.println("USB Unplugged or Terminal Disconnected");
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);delay(50);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);delay(450);
    n=n+1;
    if (n>=5){
      Serial.println("Resetting to Connect if Disconnected");
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);delay(450);
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);delay(50);
      rstc_start_software_reset(RSTC);
    }
  }
  SerialUSB.println("USB Plugged and Terminal Connected");
  Serial.println("USB Plugged and Terminal Connected");
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);delay(50);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);delay(50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do because the protocol CDC/ACM don't send that type of information so you can't detect if the Arduino is connected or not, that's why it halts. (You could make a keep-alive function but I don't know if this is possible with what you're doing)